# Axios request not sending payload when I use axios({...});

Tags: axios

[image]

To me, this code is the same, however in Chrome Dev Tools, the first request has the payload set:

[image]

But the second doesn't. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on an example from [Axios Github page](https://github.com/axios/axios#axiosconfig), the `data` property contains the payload

```
// Send a POST request
axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: '/user/12345',
  data: {
    firstName: 'Fred',
    lastName: 'Flintstone'
  }
});
```

So, in your second request, you should change **body** to **data**

Comment: Ok I'm dumb, I have a helper function that wraps the axios one that you pass the parameter `body` and it puts it into `data`, but I was debugging an endpoint and was using axios directly. Thanks!